Should users have to disclose their native language?
So, I'd be interested to hear your guys opinion on this. Often times I will write a question and get a great answer back - BUT I'm never entirely sure how native or "natural" the answer given is. I often look at people's accounts to see if they are native speakers when they answer questions - but it is not something that shows up. 
Should we have people disclose their native language upon signing up? 

I'd vote for it. Even on more mature sites like ELL, there are inaccurate answers provided by language learners and overlooked by moderators. Those are not common but every time I encounter one, I am confused and maybe frustrated. I've noticed similarly confusing answers on this site and I wasn't sure if it was the answer that's inaccurate or I am missing a perspective. The most helpful information to disambiguate that situation is the answer provider's language background.

It might work, but the idea of the Stack Exchange network is that you judge an answer based on the votes from other users and the reputation of the author.
